# Ionic 3 navPush from JSON Array

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a root page in my Ionic app that I am building from a JSON file. I need to place a page object in the array and have the navPush selector grab the value, but its not working. If I hard code a page into navPush it works, but not when pulling from JSON.

**listingPage**

```
...
<ion-row class="grid-categories">
  <ion-col width-50 class="category-item" *ngFor="let category of listing.categories">
    <background-image class="category-heading" [src]="category.image" [navPush]="category.page">
      <ion-row class="heading-row">
        <ion-col no-padding width-100>
          <h2 class="category-title">{{category.title}}</h2>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </background-image>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
...
```

`category.image` and `category.title` work as they should, but not `category.page` - If I remove the category.page and add aboutPage, it works, but of course then all the links would got to the aboutPage.

**listing.json**

```
...
"categories": [
    {
        "title": "About MSNVM",
        "image": "./assets/images/listing/200x200basquet.png",
        "page": "aboutPage"
    },
    {
        "title": "Plaque Locator",
        "image": "./assets/images/listing/200x200boxeo.png",
        "page": "aboutPage"
    },
    {
        "title": "Make A Donation",
        "image": "./assets/images/listing/200x200crossfit.png",
        "page": "aboutPage"
    },
    {
        "title": "Visit Memorial",
        "image": "./assets/images/listing/200x200futbol.png",
        "page": "aboutPage"
    }

]
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it supposed to be `"page": "AboutPage"`? (capital A as it goes for the class names)